# Correct way to make function available in multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel I have the following model:

```
class Product extends Model {}
```

which contains the function:

```
public function setThumbnailAttribute($value) {}
```

I have multiple models which should contain the same `setThumbnailAttribute()` function. What is the correct way to do this using Laravel or basic PHP functionality?

Comment: depends on what the function does. If it is an update function, the best would be to call the update function once instead of for every model.

Comment: You need to do with controllers if your method is general purpose and do some functionality. In model you should put your DB code only. But you can do that by importing the model to a controller where you want this method.

Comment: it is a manipulation function. It want to avoid using the same 40 lines of code in each model/class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use polymorphism if this models have multiple realizations of this method. However, if method universal for models, choose second.

   ```
   class Product extends AbstractThumbnailedModel
   {
       public function setThumbnailAttribute(Thumbnail $thumb)
       {
           // implement setter for Product
       }
   } 

   class AnotherProduct extends AbstractThumbnailedModel
   {
       public function setThumbnailAttribute(Thumbnail $thumb)
       {
           // implement setter for AnotherProduct
       }
   } 

   abstract class AbstractThumbnailModel extends Model 
   {
       abstract public function setThumbnailAttribute(Thumbnail $thumb);
   }
   ```
2. Use traits.  Create trait Thumbnailed and use it when needed in models.

   ```
   trait Thumbnailed 
   {
        public function setThumbnailedAttribute(Thumbnail $thumb)
        {
            // here implementaition which will share with needed models
        }
   }

   class Product extends Model
   {
       use Thumbnailed;
       // Use it!
   } 

   class AnotherProduct extends Model
   {
       use Thumbnailed;
       // same method implementation. Just use it!

   }
   ```

P.S. Sorry for Google translate

Answer (score 6):

Create a base model that extends Model, and add the function to this.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public function setThumbnailAttribute($value) 
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

You can then extend any of your models using the new base models to have access to this function.

```
class Product extends BaseModel 
{

}
```

This same logic can be applied to controllers as well, on the basis of accessing a global function.

Comment: This is a bad idea, cause ALL models in your app will be have this method. Laravel models are already very fat, I would prefer the composition.

Comment: @maches not ALL, only the models that extend this. You can extend any models with `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` or with `BaseModel`, they can work at the same time. Ergo, no different to a trait

Comment: `class Item extends Model { }` $item-> setThumbnailAttribute('test'); "Call to undefined function".